# Is there a way to set a destination to unzip for gzip files when a user double clicks on the archive. Looking for a Scala/java solution

Tags: scala

Is there a way to get a gzip archive file to unzip to a different destination when a user double clicks on the archive? Currently, my compression code looks something like this in Scala:

```
val filename = SetFilename.getOrElse {
  val path = files.head.getAbsolutePath
  val baseUrl = FilenameUtils.getFullPathNoEndSeparator(path)
  ...
}

val output = new File(filename)
val fos = new FileOutputStream(output)
val gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos))

try {
  files.foreach { input =>
    val fis = new FileInputStream(input)
    try {
      ioStream(fis, gzos)
      gzos.flush()
    }
    finally {
      fis.close()
    }

  }
}
finally {
  gzos.close()
  fos.close()
}
```

IS there any way to tell the compressed files to decompress in a different destination when a user double clicks on the archive?

Answer (score 1):

It is not the `gzip` archive that decides it will be unzipped in the same location, it's something the operating system you're unzipping it on decides.

If you need to unzip into a specific place, you should look for a packaging solution like [`deb`](https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-create-a-debian-deb-package/) for Ubuntu or Debian systems; or [`dmg`](https://www.technorms.com/30882/create-dmg-files-in-mac-os-x) for OSX.